# Need help to get the script name as a variable vs manual entry

Tags: sql

I have a table that stores every time a script is run. My issue is that I have to enter in the script name manually in the '????" and am looking for a way so it would automatically just pass the script name into the insert statement. My current script is (see below)

---

```
declare @ScriptName varchar(100)

--Replace ???? with the script name being executed
Set @ScriptName = '?????'

insert into dbhistory (dbh_memo, dbh_user, dbh_nowversion)
                        Values(@ScriptName, 'Boss','Version 758')
```

---

Comment: What do you mean the script  being executed? What's the context?

Comment: correct for example right now i would put in Set @ScriptName = 'storeproc_name.sql' and the table would show storeproc_name.sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get the name of the stored procedure (I don't know if that's what you mean by "script") and if this is SQL Server, you can use this:

```
SET @ScriptName = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
```

Comment: this returned null in the table :(

Comment: nope, just adding to the bottom of a script. The script alters the stored procs or table information. My apologies if my terminology is not correct very much a newbie with sql

Comment: Yeah, the code I gave you has to be run within a stored proc.  If this is just a SQL script, I'm guessing the only way to do what you want is to set the value manually.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your present query into a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbhistoryUpdate
  @ScriptName varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO dbhistory (
    dbh_memo, 
    dbh_user, 
    dbh_nowversion
  )
  VALUES (
    'Executing Script ' + @ScriptName,
    'Boss',
    'Version 758'
  );
END
```

Then you'd be able to invoke it like this:

```
EXEC dbhistoryUpdate 'your_value'
```